# subexpressions evaluation order

Tags: c, c99, standards

I've looked at [SO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1336.pdf) under J.1 Unspecified behavior:

```
"The order in which subexpressions are evaluated and the order in which side effects
take place, except as specified for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma
operators (6.5)."
```

Does this means that in

```
func1() + func2();
```

func2() may be preformed before func1(), or even during func1() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) there is a sequence point between function calls but the order of evaluation of the operands to `+` is not specified so `func1` may be called before or after `func2` but the function calls must not overlap or be interleaved in any way.

This means that each of `func1` and `func2` can, if desired, interact with some shared data without having that data change under it in an unexpected way.

Comment: yes, the plus operator is a sequence point, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: In the current standard: 6.5/10, I believe.

Comment: The plus operator itself doesn't imply a sequence point, but because it's arguments are both function calls there are two sequence points before + is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Not during, but sure, either 1 then 2 or 2 then 1.

Comment: The contents of a function that's called aren't themselves sub-subexpressions :)

Comment: @Liran: see section **6.5.2.2 Function calls** /10 and also the note 84) `In other words, function executions do not ``interleave'' with each other.`